# Вывести записи за последние сутки + отступить сутки с условиями

Tags: mysql, sql

помогите скорректировать запрос

Вывести записи со статусом true у которых за последние сутки не было предела по лимиту (`current_limit` < `day_limit`) и тут же все со статусом true которые больше более суток (за прошлые сутки не учитываются, т.е. просто отчет через минус день)

```
SELECT `id`, `key` FROM `products` WHERE `status` = 1 AND 
(`current_limit` < `day_limit` AND `last_use` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
AND
( DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) < `last_use`)
```

last_use это timestamp

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `day_limit` int NOT NULL,
  `current_limit` int NOT NULL,
  `last_use` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `key`, `status`, `day_limit`, `current_limit`, `last_use`, `comment`) VALUES
(5, 'key1', 1, 30, 0, '2022-07-19 21:00:00', 'test'),
(6, 'key2', 1, 30, 30, '2022-07-21 21:00:00', 'test'),
(7, 'key3', 1, 30, 5, '2022-07-23 07:34:51', 'sdsa');

 
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

 
 
ALTER TABLE `products`
  MODIFY `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Добавьте требуемый результат для показанных данных, с пояснениями. Ну и три записи - маловато для охвата всех возможных сочетаний...

Comment: Я в начале поста писал о результате. Вывести в одном запросе записи с status = 1 которые не достигли дневного лимита за последние сутки, это колонки current_limit (сколько сейчас есть) и day_limit (сколько можно за день) и записи более суток у которых так же стоит status = 1 и уже не важно что там в day_limit, current_limit.

Comment: Если разделить запрос на 2 разных, то оно вроде работает нормально

SELECT `id`, `key` FROM `products` WHERE `status` = 1 AND (`current_limit` < `day_limit` AND `last_use` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ;

Comment: SELECT `id`, `key` FROM `products` WHERE `status` = 1 AND  DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) > `last_use`;

Answer (score 0):

Если я всё правильно понял, то нужно AND на OR поменять

```
SELECT `id`, `key` 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `status` = 1 AND 
(`current_limit` < `day_limit` AND 
`last_use` > DATE_SUB(@CurrentDay, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
OR
(`last_use` < DATE_SUB(@CurrentDay, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: Нет, нужно именно И. И то и другое одновременно, как два запроса вместе, два where, я хз как по другому описать еще.

Comment: Впрочем задачу я решил, не знаю на сколько элегантно и может есть лучше. Но через UNION соединил запросы.

Comment: Нет, нет, OR как раз в этом случае работает как UNION, типа если на словах сказать "Покажи мне в ОДНОЙ выборке записи, которые соответствуют правилу один ИЛИ (OR) записи соответствующие правилу два." Это ране работает не как "Покажи мне первые или вторые", OR именно объединит их.

Comment: А на счёт элегантности я так скажу, можно написать и так и так, повлиять это может только на производительность, которую возможно проверить лишь на больших объёмах данных. Один навороченный запрос это не всегда круто, порой приходится не только UNION использовать, но и разделять на несколько запросов через табличные переменные или временные таблицы - главное это производительность.

Comment: P.S. Я 10 лет уже занимаюсь разработкой БД, но лишь пару дней назад меня озарило, что здесь можно не только потреблять, но и помогать в свободную минутку))) надеюсь, что у Вас всё получилось) если что пишите)